# How to redirect urls like mysite.com/? to mysite.com (no '?') django or nginx?

Tags: django, redirect, nginx

I've got the following problem:
I'm using Django under nginx.
Since some time I started working on SEO.
So now I need to redirect urls like

site.com/? to site.com/

or

site.com/some_page/? to site.com/some_page/

So, the problem is the '?'.. I can redirect if there is something after the '?' but if it's only '?' - I don't know what to do..

I tried to read the meta 'REQUEST_URI' but it is empty, and the GET is empty, but that's normal.
May be I can make some hack about it in nginx, but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do..

Are there any tips that can help?
thanks in advance.. And sorry for my English)

UPD:

Tried in nginx the following thing:

```
    if ($request_uri ~ "[?]$") {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$host/$1? permanent;
    }
```

It works great in case that the url is like

"site.com/something?"

but when it is "site.com/something?city=4&myid=10?" it redirects to "site.com/something"

so all normal parameters("city, myid") are lost. And that's not good for me, cause I need to save them.
Still need help.. It seems that it's not so easy for me to do it with nginx either.

Comment: You're not going to be able to salvage the case where there's a query string *and* another `?` at the end. Having a link somewhere to "site.com/something?" is understandable, but something like "site.com/something?city=4&myid=10?" is just a borked link, in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would use nginx, you do not need to spin up python process to make redirect, and redirects are very easy in nginx, just look at related questions.

Comment: I really tried and could'n get it working as I need it to (see updated post)

Answer (score 0):

I did not really get your question. Do you only want to redirect URLs containing or ending in '?'. In case you want to redirect all URLs, just use:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$host/$1 permanent;
```

Note the '?' at the end of your rewrite target stops the GET parameters being added to the redirection request. See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite